# lvalue required as left operand of assignment at isProcessRunning(handle)=true

Tags: c++, lvalue, openprocess

i don't get what is wrong with my code, sry if it's a silly question i'm a beginner

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Winuser.h>
#include <stdint.h>


bool isProcessRunning(HANDLE process)
  {
return WaitForSingleObject( process, 0 ) == WAIT_TIMEOUT;
  }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,7824);
    while ( isProcessRunning(handle)=true )
    {
        //code  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> (line 15 col 34) [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: `isProcessRunning(handle)==true` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `=` means assignment. For comparison you need `==`.

So what you want is

`while (isProcessRunning(handle) == true)`

or just

`while (isProcessRunning(handle))`

Comment: Vote to close questions like these as a typo instead of answering them.